# Problems with set up Wacom pen middle click button...it is impossible to rotate view

Tags: customization

My Blender version is 2.83.1
my Operating System is MacOS 10.15.5
Wacom Drivers 6.3.39-1

so...if I try to set up the first button as a middle click for having a rotating navigation control on my pen when I am in Blender, It doesn't work.
But if I do this in preference in Wacom panel for all other applications, then It works. But if I add Specific preference in the Wacom Panel for Blender, it doesn't work.

Is there anybody out there who can help me with this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried setting it up the way you want it for Blender as default and then just changing Wacom settings for other applications?

Comment: I never use macs, but on other OS if you just set the driver to use a button as middle mouse button, it works fine in blender.

Comment: Martynas Žiemys - No, I haven't. But I don't know how to set Blender as default.

Comment: Susu - Before it worked very well. Suddenly it stopped recognizing the Settings. I tried to reinstall Blender, Wacom drivers but nothing worked.